# Federated identity on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid, federated-identity

I am successful with the both methods below, to log on using federated log in for my site  on Google App Engine (Python)

```
users.create_login_url("\", "google", "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id")
users.create_login_url("\", "yahoo", "http://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid20/www.yahoo.com/xrds")
```

I wish to provide more log in options to my users. 
Can anyone help me with getting federated identity of Facebook, MySpace, Wordpress, etc..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid) mentions following direct providers of federated identities ...

- google.com/accounts/o8/id (shorter alternative: gmail.com)
- yahoo.com
- myspace.com
- aol.com
- myopenid.com

... as well as username provider federated identities:

- flickr.com/USERNAME
- USERNAME.wordpress.com
- USERNAME.blogspot.com
- USERNAME.livejournal.com
- openid.aol.com/USERNAME
- USERNAME.myopenid.com
- www.myspace.com/USERNAME

Facebook is not an OpenID provider, forcing its own standard Facebook Connect.

Comment: Facebook started to accept OpenId a while ago: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/246


The linked article show how to achieve a user-friendly login with multiple providers. You basically create links to the services you want to support using `users.create_login_url(federated_identity=...)`.

Comment: I think you can log into Facebook with OpenID but you cannot use Facebook account to log into for example stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Very thanks for the response 
dose google accepts microsoft live ids and in.com ids via open id  
i found some publishers using these two for open id, may be not on google frame work.

Comment: but what is the login url for facebook if we want to use it as open id provider

Answer (score 2):

There is a partial list of OpenID providers on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID); Facebook is not an OpenID provider, preferring to make you use Facebook Connect.  Myspace uses "myspace.com/username" as the federated identity, while wordpress uses "username.wordpress.com".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent resource for Open ID providers in the form of a nice JQuery plug-in: http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml

Comment: The OpenID site itself also provides a nice list of know providers:  [http://openid.net/get-an-openid/](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/)